# How can I span a 25ft beam?

Tags: structural, patio, beam, detached-structure

I'm planning to build a detached patio cover over an existing 24'x30' slab. I want to cover half of the slab and intend to pour new footings directly outside the existing slab. If possible I would like the beam spanning the middle of the slab to span the entire distance with no center post. I was thinking a 3 layer laminated 2x10, with offset seams could work. The roof system is less than 10 psf, using 15' 2x8 16"oc and metal roof panels. The total area of the roof is 25'5"x15'10". The exact spacing between the inside of the posts would be 24'6.5". I plan to have knee braces all around, though I didn't add them to the drawing. All of the connections would be made with Simpson connectors, also not shown in the drawing. All of the lumber would be pressure treated #2 southern yellow pine.

I'm having trouble finding spanning tables that match my application to determine what would be an appropriate beam size. I'm in Florida so there is no snow or significant additional load on the roof.

[image: mock up]

I was thinking I could use 2 10', 2 16', 1 12', and 1 14' lengths to stagger the seams. I would use construction adhesive and structural screws to bond the layers. Here is an image showing the staggered seams.

[image]

Will this work, or am I going to have to add a center post?

Comment: The IRC's standard roof live load in the absence of snow is 20 psf. Wind exerts vertically oriented pressures, however, where your wind pressures probably exceed the 20 psf. The lateral pressures probably require bracing that isn't drawn in your sketch. What's your ultimate wind speed?

Comment: The laminated 2x10s with staggered seams aren't going to work. LVLs ship in lengths up to 80 ft and with superior engineering properties, so that's your solution, but you're grossly underestimating your loads right now.

Comment: Are you subject to Pensacola FL building codes?

Comment: One word: *Hurricanes* (FL = Hurricanes, CA = Earthquakes, most of the rest of the country = Snow - it's always something...)

Comment: @popham I will be adding bracing. Ultimate wind speed here is 170. I think for the scope and budget of the project it makes sense to just be ok with a center post, as that greatly simplifies things. What else am I missing when considering roof load?

Comment: @JimStewart Yes